# Multiplicative group of a permutation matrix

Tags: matrices, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups, cyclic-groups

**My question:**

Let $M_\pi$ be the permutation matrix of an arbitrary permutation $\pi$. What is the group $\langle M_\pi \rangle$ generated by $M_\pi$ over matrix multiplication?

**My effort:**

I understand that it is a finite group and the number of elements in the group will be the period of $\pi$. If the period is $p$, will the multiplicative group of $M_\pi$ be the cyclic group $C_p$?

Comment: Do you know what a group homomorphism is?

Comment: @DanRobertson, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the natural group homomorphism $\phi$ that takes a permutation to its matrix representation (to prove: this is a well-defined function and homomorphism). Then it is easy to show that $\phi$ is injective and so for $\pi \in S_n,$ we get $\langle \pi \rangle \cong \phi(\langle \pi \rangle) \cong \langle \phi(\pi)\rangle$ where $\phi(\pi)\equiv M_\pi$.

Comment: Is $\langle \pi \rangle \cong C_p$  if $p$ is the period of $\pi$?

Comment: For any $x$ in any finite group, $\langle x\rangle\cong C_n$ where $n$ is the order (aka period) of $x.$